# FileOutputStream("dest_path") throws exception in android 9 (pie)

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, save-image

I have read so many threads on SO and other platforms as well but nothing seems to solve the problem.
This is how I am doing it in kotlin,

```
val dest = getDestFile()  // method defined bellow
if(dest != null){
    try {
        // dest = full_path/main_dir/nested_dir/another_nested_dir/IMG_123456789.jpg
        val out = FileOutputStream(dest)  **//This line gives crash**
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        inputStream.close()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

fun getDestFile() : File?{
    var file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "main_dir/nested_dir")
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir()
        file = File(file, "another_nested_dir")  //RESULT: full_path/main_dir/nested_dir/another_nested_dir
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir()
            file = File(file, "IMG-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg") //RESULT: full_path/main_dir/nested_dir/another_nested_dir/IMG-123456789.jpg
            if (file.getParentFile() != null) {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile()
                }
            } else {
                file.parentFile.mkdirs()
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile()
                }
            }
            return file
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

I have mentioned where the crash is but I am unable to find why is this happening. The application is crashing with a message,

> File does not exists

The same code is working perfectly on android 8.1 and bellow. Please share your expertise about this.

Comment: Are you mixing up `dest` and `dst`?

Comment: What is the value of dest and dst? Which paths are you talking about?

Comment: What is the value of `file.getAbsilutePath()`?

Comment: Bear in mind that this code does not work on Android 10 (by default) or Android 11+ (for all apps). You do not have access to arbitrary locations on external storage anymore. Please consider doing something else for your content storage that does not involve deprecated methods on `Environment` like `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: hey @blackapps I'm sorry for inconvenience, that was a spelling mistake, i have edited my answer and added a comment about what the value of dest is. Please have a look i think its clear now.

Comment: hi @CommonsWare I think your comment has weight. The code is not working on 9 and higher. What would be the alternatives then ? what would you suggest about storing images and videos to a directory which is created by my app like in the above code ? such as "MyApp/ABC/IMG-123.jpg". how would I do that for all devices and versions ?

Comment: "What would be the alternatives then ?" -- primarily, your options are the Storage Access Framework and `MediaStore`. See the blog post series starting with [this one](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare i got it, but what if I want a separate folder in the storage indicating that its my app's folder and that contain the images and videos. such as whatsapp has its own folder and many other apps.

Comment: If you use the Storage Access Framework, the user can choose where the user wants the user's content to go. If you use `MediaStore`, and you want to create a subdirectory under a standard media directory, use `RELATIVE_PATH`. Apps, including WhatsApp, will no longer be able to create directories off of the external storage root directory anymore.

Comment: wouldn't it create complexities to handle the data if you allow user to choose the destination of his/her choosing ? I don't know why i feel it as a headache for me not to be able to create my own directory outside of standard media directory. i mean we are bound now. well i think we have to stick to the point that google says.  what else can we do.